# Flutter: Textfield controller on a nested listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

hello can someone help me on nested listview.
as you can see from the image below, i made two listview.builders.
first listview.builder(context, i) is for the headers "ChildWO:" and a description below.
Than another listview.builder(context, index) for under it that contains data about it (shown in card widgets).

My problem is, whenever I input a value inside the textfield.
every textfield that have the same position will be filled up.
for example "55". every first card of it will be filled with "55".

Is there a way wherein I can set the controller of the textfield to have it like,
"controller: _qtyInputtedList[i][index]"?

for now, my controller is set at controller: _qtyInputtedList[index].

Thank you.

```
Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                    child: ListView.separated(
                        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                              height: 1,
                            ),
                        itemCount: mainParent.CHILDREN?.length ?? 0,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          // _qtyInputtedList.add(new TextEditingController());
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 10, 2, 0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Child WO: ${mainParent.CHILDREN![i].WONUM}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'NunitoLight'),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${mainParent.CHILDREN![i].WODESC}',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontFamily: 'NunitoLight'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: mainParent
                                      .CHILDREN![i].MATERIALS!.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    _qtyInputtedList.add(new TextEditingController());
                                    final post = mainParent
                                        .CHILDREN![i].MATERIALS![index];
                                    //tileKey.add(GlobalKey(debugLabel: "index :$i"));
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding: mainParent
                                                  .CHILDREN![i]
                                                  .MATERIALS![index]
                                                  .STRUCTURE ==
                                              "1"
                                          ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                              10, 4, 10, 4)
                                          : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                              20, 4, 10, 4),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                          onLongPress: () {
                                            //itemNum will be used for component list endpoint
                                            itemNum =
                                                '${mainParent.CHILDREN![i].MATERIALS![index].ITEMNUM}';
                                            mainParent
                                                        .CHILDREN![i]
                                                        .MATERIALS![index]
                                                        .STRUCTURE ==
                                                    "1"
                                                ? _displayDialogListMaterials(
                                                    context)
                                                : null;
                                          },
                                          child: ExpansionTileCard(
                                              //key: tileKey[i],
                                              //key: tileKey[i],
                                              //baseColor: Colors.grey[800],
                                              baseColor: mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index]
                                                          .STRUCTURE ==
                                                      "1"
                                                  ? Color(0xff3A3845)
                                                  : Color(0xff826F66),

                                              // baseColor: Colors.red[700],
                                              expandedTextColor:
                                                  Colors.black,
                                              expandedColor: mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index]
                                                          .STRUCTURE ==
                                                      "1"
                                                  ? Color(0xff3A3845)
                                                  : Colors.grey[600],
                                              trailing: Transform.scale(
                                                scale: 2.5,
                                                child: Theme(
                                                  data: ThemeData(
                                                    unselectedWidgetColor:
                                                        Colors.grey[
                                                            700], // Your color
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    margin:
                                                        EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                    width: 14,
                                                    height: 14,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    child: Checkbox(
                                                        hoverColor:
                                                            Colors.white,
                                                        activeColor: Colors
                                                            .green[700],
                                                        value:
                                                            selectedItems.contains(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index]),
                                                        onChanged:
                                                            (bool? value) {
                                                              if(selectedItems.contains(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index])) {
                                                                selectedItems.remove(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index]);
                                                                selectedItems.remove(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index].ITEMNUM);
                                                                selectedItems.remove(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .WONUM);
                                                                selectedItems.remove(_qtyInputtedList[index].text);
                                                              } else {
                                                                selectedItems.add(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index]);
                                                                selectedItems.add(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index].ITEMNUM);
                                                                selectedItems.add(mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .WONUM);
                                                                selectedItems.add(_qtyInputtedList[index].text);
                                                              }
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            print(selectedItems.toString());
                                                            //if you want to reload loadparent2
                                                            // dataFuture = loadParent2();
                                                          });
                                                        }),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              // leading: Icon(
                                              //   Icons.warning_amber,
                                              //   color: Colors.white,
                                              //   size: 60.0,
                                              // ),
                                              leading: mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index]
                                                          .STRUCTURE ==
                                                      "0"
                                                  ? Container(
                                                      width: 60.0,
                                                      child: TextField(
                                                        controller: _qtyInputtedList[index],
                                                        keyboardType:
                                                            TextInputType
                                                                .number,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 20),
                                                        decoration:
                                                            InputDecoration(
                                                          filled: true,
                                                          fillColor:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                          border:
                                                              InputBorder
                                                                  .none,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  : null,
                                              title: Text(
                                                '${mainParent.CHILDREN![i].MATERIALS![index].ITEMNUM}',
                                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                                    .textTheme
                                                    .bodyText2!
                                                    .copyWith(
                                                        fontSize: 25,
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight
                                                                .bold),
                                              ),
                                              subtitle: Text(
                                                '${mainParent.CHILDREN![i].MATERIALS![index].ITEMDESCRIPTION}',
                                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                                    .textTheme
                                                    .bodyText2!
                                                    .copyWith(
                                                        fontSize: 16,
                                                        color:
                                                            Colors.white),
                                              ),
                                              children: mainParent
                                                          .CHILDREN![i]
                                                          .MATERIALS![index]
                                                          .STRUCTURE ==
                                                      "0"
                                                  ? <Widget>[
                                                      Divider(
                                                        thickness: 3.0,
                                                        height: 3.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      Align(
                                                        alignment: Alignment
                                                            .centerLeft,
                                                        child: Padding(
                                                          padding:
                                                              const EdgeInsets
                                                                  .symmetric(
                                                            horizontal:
                                                                16.0,
                                                            vertical: 5.0,
                                                          ),
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            "Planned QTY: ${mainParent.CHILDREN![i].MATERIALS![index].QUANTITYPLAN}"
                                                            "\n"
                                                            "Warehouse Balance: 30",
                                                            style: Theme.of(
                                                                    context)
                                                                .textTheme
                                                                .bodyText2!
                                                                .copyWith(
                                                                    fontSize:
                                                                        22),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      ButtonBar(
                                                        alignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .start,
                                                        buttonHeight: 52.0,
                                                        buttonMinWidth:
                                                            90.0,
                                                        children: <
                                                            Widget>[],
                                                      ),
                                                    ]
                                                  : <Widget>[])),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: you want to add different value from different text field? but right now you put value in one textfield this value is apply all textfield,Im correct?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil If I try to put a value example 55 from the first index. all first index will have 55. notice the number 66 value above, this one was ok but if there was another list of multiple cards that will also have a 66 on its 2nd index. i hope i was clear

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to split your code to reuseable widgets, by this way you don't need to care about controller and how to declare it they are differences, code look short and clearly, below is example.

Example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Student {
  int id;
  String name;
  Student(this.id, this.name);
}

class Class {
  String name;
  List<Student> students;
  Class(this.name, [this.students = const []]);
}

class RenderStudent extends StatefulWidget {
  const RenderStudent({required this.student, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Student student;

  @override
  RenderStudentState createState() => RenderStudentState();
}

class RenderStudentState extends State<RenderStudent> {
  Student get student => widget.student;

  late TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.student.name);
    controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Student id: ${student.id}",
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RenderClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const RenderClass({required this.clas, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Class clas;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text("Class ${clas.name}", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: clas.students.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              child: RenderStudent(
                student: clas.students[i],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  final items = [
    Class('A1', [Student(1, "Carter")]),
    Class('B1', [Student(2, "Join"), Student(2, "Smith"), Student(2, "Lara")]),
  ];
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => RenderClass(clas: items[i]),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi man. do you have example if the list is nested? thanks!

Comment: @KimLo check the updated example in answer

Comment: I followed your code and tried using it on my code. i'm kinda confuse since i'm using data from an API post request. You are using here a static list. do you have sample where data came from an API? thanks again